# Fail to reinstall spacy with python 3.7

Tags: python, spacy

I am using python 3.7 , I want to downgrade spacy version but when I run pip install -U spacy==1.9.0 , I got this error  ERROR: Failed building wheel for thinc

[error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpLtg.png)

Comment: Please post the full error message

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pip uninstall spacy` first, and then `pip install -U spacy==1.9.0`

Comment: I did that but when i run pip list I didn't even find spacy package. .